# Tuning Tomcat 7 on windows (for Alfresco)

Tags: windows, tomcat, java, alfresco

I have installed Tomcat7 as a service on a windows server 64bit 2008 R2 to run Alfresco (4.2.c). I have 48G of ram.

I have read Tomcat tuning tutorial with the JVM settings for memory. To edit the settings I just the tomcat7w //ES//alfrescoTomcat util and I have set my initial and max memory settings to 32/42 in the Java options tab like this:

-Xms32G -Xmx42G

A few questions:

when I look at the task manager, I see tomcat only using 8G of memory. Why?
When I read the Alfresco windows tuning paper: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Windows_Service_HOW-TO it shows to use --JvmMs and --JvmMx for tomcat. What is the difference?
Any tips? This is my first windows install of Alfresco.